# Characterization of the $m$-torsion points of an elliptic curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

Let $(E,\mathcal{O})$ be the elliptic curve of equation
$$
f=Y^{2}+a_{1}XY+a_{3}Y-X^{3}-a_{2}X^{2}-a_{4}X-a_{6},
$$

$\alpha:K(E)\rightarrow K(E)$   the derivation such that
$$
\alpha(X)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y},\quad \alpha(Y)=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}
$$
and $m$ a positive integer. I have to prove that, if we are working in a field $K$ of characteristic $\geq m+1$, and $\mathcal{L}(m\mathcal{O})=\langle 1,f_{1},\ldots,f_{m-1}\rangle$, then the $m$-torsion points of $E$ different from $\mathcal{O}$ coincide with
the zeros of
$$
\det (\alpha^{i}(f_{j}))_{1\leq i,j\leq m-1}.
$$
By the way, what can be said about the number of zeros of that determinant?

$\textbf{Edit:}$ In fact, that determinant vanishes at $p\in E-\{\mathcal{O}\}$ if and only if (see the comments that follow mercio's answer) there exists $g\in\mathcal{L}(m\mathcal{O})$ such that $\alpha(g)|_{p}=\cdots=\alpha^{m-1}(g)|_{p}=0$. This reduces the problem (because of mercio's answer again) to show that this is equivalent to $g$ having a zero of order $m$ at $p$. Is this true?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, may I ask: what do you mean by $\omega^i$?

Comment: @lee I have edited the question. Thank you for making me notice my mistake!

Comment: no this doesn't make sense, how is $d/ dY$ an element of $K(E)$ ?

Comment: @mercio You are right, I have edited the question again, thank you!

Comment: Oh, nice. Now it makes sense to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $P$ be a point of $E$ different from $\mathcal O$.

the determinant vanishes at $P$ if and only if there is a linear combination of the $f_j$ (which means a function with poles of order at most $m$ at $\mathcal O$), such that its first $m-1$ derivatives at $P$ all vanish.

By adding a suitable constant to that function if necessary, this means you have a function with a pole of order $m$ at $\mathcal O$ and a zero of order $m$ at $P$ (and nothing else because you can't have any additional pole)

But this means exactly that $m(\mathcal O - P)$ is a principal divisor, so that once you fix $\mathcal O$ as the origin of the group law, $P$ is a point of order $m$.

Comment: Ok, thank you! The only think I don't get to understand is why the determinant vanishes at $P$ if and only if there exists $g\in\mathcal{L}(m\mathcal{O})$ such that its first $m-1$ derivatives at $P$ all vanish.

Comment: In fact, lee's comment has made me notice that I was misunderstanding the meaning of $\omega^{i}$. Could you help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: @JosuaJones I really am not sure either (you better double check in whatever source your exercise come froms), but I would guess that if $f \in \mathcal O_E$ is a meromorphic function on $E$ and $\omega \in \Omega_E$ then $df = (\omega(f)) \omega$. Or you can view $\omega$ as an actual derivation (a $\Bbb C$-linear map $\mathcal O_E \to \mathcal O_E$ satisfying the product rule). Since $\omega$ doesn't vanish, the zeroes of $\omega(f)$ are the zeroes of $df$. I am not sure how best to relate higher order "derivatives" of $f$ with the $\omega^i(f)$

Comment: Excuse me, do you know if there is an easy way to find out how many zeros does that determinant have?

Comment: @JosuaJones The group of $m$ torsion points (over the algebraic closure) is $(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^2$ so there should be $m^2-1$ zeroes on that determinant.